# Does the title and description attribute of images ever get shown?

Tags: images

If the answer is case-by-case basis, check out this blog post: http://www.inquisitr.com/3078539/starting-in-west-virginia-bernie-sanders-could-win-8-of-the-next-9-primaries/

Does the title and description of images ever get shown on WordPress sites?

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from the [Yoast](https://yoast.com/image-seo-alt-tag-and-title-tag-optimization/) website:

> The alt and title attributes of an image are commonly referred to as alt tag or alt text and title tag even though they’re not technically tags. The alt text describes what’s on the image and the function of the image on the page. So if you have an image that’s used as a button to buy product X, the alt text would say: “button to buy product X”.

If these tags are filled out, they will always write out in the HTML. Although they will not display directly to the screen. `title` will provide users with additional information about the image if they hover over it. `alt` will provide screen readers a description of the images. More on that later.

For the descriptions, this is more commonly seen on the "attachment page" for an image. But would be largely dependent on the theme developer. From [Title, Caption, Alt Text, and Description: Harnessing the Power of WordPress Image Metadata](https://mor10.com/power-of-wordpress-image-metadata/):

> If you add text to the description field that text will be stored as post content for the attachment post. That means if someone lands on the attachment post page for the image they will see the long description (provided the current theme supports it).

**Example:** `<img src="path/to/file.jpg" title="Your Title" alt="Alternate Text" />`

### Accessible Images

In terms of accessibility of images. If the image contains text, provides information not also explained on the page or is complex in nature an `alt` tag should always be used to describe the image.

If the image provides no additional value other than to break up content or provide something decorative (such as using an image as an line break) you should always use `alt=""`.

Additional information on Accessibility of images can be found on the w3.org's WAI [Images Concepts](http://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/) page.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about the description.

Comment: @User - My apologies. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether any of the four (alt, title, description, caption) texts related to an image get shown, depends on the theme. If you instert images manually in a post, it depends on what you do.

Technically, images are treated like special posts, with a title (title tag), content (description) and excerpt (caption). You will see lightbox plugins extract this information.

So, yes, it is useful to fill in all four, if only if you decide to switch themes in the future.